# Refer class in another .java file in my program

Tags: java

I am absolutely new to Java and having trouble referencing a class that I have declared in another .java file. I read a lot about it on the Oracle Website and also many stackoverflow questions, but couldn't solve the problem. Here are the steps I have taken:

**Set the class path.**
I am running this on UNIX. So I typed in
`% java -classpath /users/myUserName/algs4/assignment1`. Instead of changing the class path it gives me a long list of other options.

**Include the 'package name'** in each of my .java files which have class definitions I want to refer to.

I also ensured that all my files that I want to refer are in the same directory. 
Here is some of my code:

```
package assignment1;
public class Percolation
{
    private int[][] grid;
    ....
    //Other method definitions etc.
   public Percolation(int N)
   {
      uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(N);
      grid = new int[N][N];
      ...
      //Other code

   }

 }
```

My WeightedQuickUnionUF class is also defined as:

```
package assignment1;
public class WeightedQuickUnionUF {
    private int[] id;    // id[i] = parent of i
    private int[] sz;    // sz[i] = number of objects in subtree rooted at i
    private int count;   // number of components

    //Create an empty union find data structure with N isolated sets.
    public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int N) {
        count = N;
        id = new int[N];
        sz = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            id[i] = i;
            sz[i] = 1;
        }
     }
}
```

But now when I compile using javac Percolation.java. It gives me the errors:

```
Percolation.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WeightedQuickUnionUF
location: class assignment1.Percolation
WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
^
```

I get it that it is because the compiler doesn't know what is the class WeightedQuickUnionUF. It cannot refer it. But how do I do it then? I have already tried the popular solutions.

I am not using any IDE. Just a text editor and then compiling it on the terminal.

(algs4 folder has files like stdlib.jar and others)

EDIT: I missed the 'new' keyword. I have added that. Also I am compiling my WeightedQuickUnionUF class before Percolation.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java` command is not setting the classpath but trying to run a java class. That's why the long option list.

You can specify the classpath upon compilation: run `javac -classpath . assignment1/Percolation.java` from the algs4 directory. Pay attention to the dot it means current directory.

There is no need to compile the files in order.

To run your program: `java -cp . assignment1.Percolation` from the algs4 directory.

Comment: Tested on my machine and it compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: Thanks works! Just one more question, why do I compile from the algs4 directory and not the assignment1?

Comment: you should compile from the algs: like in the above answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to first compile the dependencies, ie, in your case the `WeightedQuickUnionUF` class.

And if you want an anonymous object, declare it along with the `new` keyword :

```
uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(N);
```

Or use it as mentioned in another answer.

Since that answer is deleted(I don't see it anymore), the other way around is to have a named object:

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF myObj;
```

..

```
myObj = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(N);
uf = myObj;
```

Comment: I compiled the WeightedQuickUnionUF class first. And also I added the new keyword, but the same message. Percolation.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WeightedQuickUnionUF

Answer (score 0):

You must compile the classes in the

```
order of the flow of the Object Graph.
```

That means Percolation class **CANNOT** be compiled **before the WeightedQuickUnionUF get compiled.**

So first compile the WeightedQuickUnionUF then Percolation.

I think you have even missed out the `new` keyword...while initializing WeightedQuickUnionUF(N);

```
uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(N);
```

Comment: I compiled the WeightedQuickUnionUF class first. (no errors). Also I added the new keyword, but the same problem.